# Change detection not run when the errors are set on reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I am on angular 7 and i am using reactive forms for one of my forms and the code is as below. (Stackblitz [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-bug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts))

**Template**

```
 <form [formGroup]="SignupForm" *ngIf="SignupForm">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" formControlName = "username">
   <div *ngIf="SignupForm.errors?.errors">Error</div>
 </form>
```

**Typescript**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  SignupForm: FormGroup;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({
        'username': new FormControl('Value'),
        'email': new FormControl()
      });
      this.SignupForm.setErrors({errors: 'Error'});
    })
  }
}
```

As you can see i am trying to set the error as soon as the form is initialized (In my actual case i would do some validation based on back end data and then do this. ). But the error doesn't seem to show up even though `SignupForm.errors` is set with the error object.

But if i do

```
setTimeout(() => { this.SignupForm.setErrors({errors: 'Error'});})
```

Everything works fine. Am i doing something wrong or is it an angular bug which i can report. Please help. Thank you.

**Note**

Actually the thing is my form comes from the backend which is asynchronous. After the i create the form from the metadata i do the validation and set the errors. So moving to any life cycle hook would not change any behavior i suppose.

Comment: I have a feeling that the error message is not showing up because your form is pristine. Have you tried to mark the form or individual controls as Dirty and Touched? If I can remember the methods you need to call are markAsDirty and markAsTouched

Comment: But it seems to be working after setTimeout. If control being pristine was the issue it should not have worked that way either right ? Correct me if i am missing anything.

Comment: That's true, have you tried moving the code to the ngAfterViewInit hook?

Comment: ngAfterViewInit would work. Also `<div [hidden]="SignupForm.errors?.errors">Error</div>` would work

Comment: Actually the thing is my form comes from the backend which is asynchronous. After the i create the form from the metadata i do the validation and set the errors. So moving to any lifecycle hook would not change any behavior i suppose.

Comment: @Hiru i donot want to use [hidden] as it leaves the element in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

can you please write **setErrors** on **ngAfterViewInit**

here is the example 
**TS**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
SignupForm: FormGroup;

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({
     'username': new FormControl('Value'),
    'email': new FormControl()
  });
}

ngAfterViewInit(){
     this.SignupForm.setErrors({errors: 'Error'});
}
```

let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: Actually the thing is my form comes from the backend which is asynchronous. After the i create the form from the metadata i do the validation and set the errors. So moving to any lifecycle hook would not change any behavior i suppose.

Comment: so you are creating a form from the response of the api am i right? if yes can you try to call the api in ngAfterViewInit and initialize Formgroup and errors there.

Comment: Yeah. Same issue will be there if we call on ngAfterViewInit. I don't think it is related to lifecycle as things are happening asynchronously. And just to be sure, in my actual environment its already in ngAfterViewInit and the same issue persists.